# Add/Remove class on click in pure JS

Tags: javascript

I've always used `jQuery`, it's easy there, but I decided to switch to pure `JS` and ran into difficulties.
When I click on the button, I want the `crossOut` class to be added to the 3 elements with the `appOrd` class, and the button itself becomes inactive (the bootstrap class - `disabled`).
And the second button, `Resume`, does the opposite.
But nothing works, please tell me what is the problem?

P.S.I suppose there is an error in the `const`, perhaps it cannot be used like that?

UPD-1. Barmar suggested a typo, corrected it.

UPD-2. It is necessary that the class is added only to the current row of the table.

```js
const hasClass = document.querySelector('.appOrd').classList.contains('crossOut');

document.querySelector('.completeBtn').onclick=function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if( !hasClass) {
        document.querySelector('.appOrd').classList.add('crossOut');
        document.querySelector('.resumeBtn').classList.remove('disabled');
        this.classList.add('disabled');
    }
}

document.querySelector('.resumeBtn').onclick=function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(hasClass) {
        document.querySelector('.appOrd').classList.remove('crossOut');
        document.querySelector('.completeBtn').classList.remove('disabled');
        this.classList.add('disabled');
    }
}
```

```css
.crossOut{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Phone number</th>
          <th scope="col">Application time</th>
          <th scope="col">Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <td scope="row" class="appOrd">Name</td>
          <td class="appOrd">Phone number</td>
          <td class="appOrd">2021-02-07 08:40:48</td>
          <td>
            <a class="btn btn-success resumeBtn disabled" href="#">Resume</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger completeBtn" href="#">Complete</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You have two `onclick` functions for Complete button, how is that supposed to work? Should one of them be on the Resume button?

Comment: And `if (hasClass)` checks the variable that was set when the page was loaded. Shouldn't it check whether the element currently has the class?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you're right, I didn't notice. There should be resumeBtn.
And you are right about hasClass. How to make it check at the current time? Add it inside each function?

Comment: Why do you need to check? There's no harm in adding the class if already has it, or removing it if it's not there.

Comment: In another answer, someone did a check, I thought so correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `querySelectorAll()` to select more than one element, and then update the class on all of them. This can be done with `.forEach()` to loop over them.

Similarly, use `querySelectorAll()` to add the `onclick` handler to each of the buttons.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.completeBtn').forEach(el => el.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let row = this.closest("tr");
  row.querySelectorAll('.appOrd').forEach(el => el.classList.add('crossOut'));
  row.querySelector('.resumeBtn').classList.remove('disabled');
  this.classList.add('disabled');
});

document.querySelectorAll('.resumeBtn').forEach(el => el.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let row = this.closest("tr");
  row.querySelectorAll('.appOrd').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('crossOut'));
  row.querySelector('.completeBtn').classList.remove('disabled');
  this.classList.add('disabled');
});
```

```css
.crossOut {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone number</th>
      <th scope="col">Application time</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td scope="row" class="appOrd">Name</td>
      <td class="appOrd">Phone number</td>
      <td class="appOrd">2021-02-07 08:40:48</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-success resumeBtn disabled" href="#">Resume</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger completeBtn" href="#">Complete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td scope="row" class="appOrd">Name 2</td>
      <td class="appOrd">Phone number 2</td>
      <td class="appOrd">2021-02-06 09:00:50</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-success resumeBtn disabled" href="#">Resume</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger completeBtn" href="#">Complete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Now there is another problem, because I have a table, I need the class to be added to only one row, and it is added to all.

Comment: Then you should use `this.closest("tr").querySelectorAll(".appOrd")`

Comment: Very similar to how you'd do it with jQuery.

Comment: I decided to practice in JS, and also switched to bootstrap 5, it no longer supports jQuery).

Comment: I'm not saying you should use jQuery, just that the logic is the same. So if you're already familiar with how to do it in jQuery, you don't need to learn anything new.

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood you). Thanks again! BTW, could you add closest ('tr') to your answer?) And then resumeBtn for some reason does not work for me).

Comment: Why isn't that requirement in the question? The other answers show how to use that.

Comment: Now I will add, I just did not know that it would be so, so I didn't add it right away.

Answer (score 1):

the buttons are for the row that the they are in, so it is better to do it this way

```js
const resume = (src, enable) => {
  const tr = src.parentElement.parentElement;
  const nameElts = tr.querySelectorAll('.appOrd');

  if (enable) {
    nameElts.forEach(e => e.classList.remove('crossOut'));
  } else {
    nameElts.forEach(e => e.classList.add('crossOut'));
  }

  const completeBtn = tr.querySelector(".completeBtn");
  const resumeBtn = tr.querySelector(".resumeBtn");

  if (enable) {
    completeBtn.classList.remove('disabled');
    resumeBtn.classList.add('disabled');
  } else {
    resumeBtn.classList.remove('disabled');
    completeBtn.classList.add('disabled');
  }
}

document.querySelectorAll(".completeBtn").forEach(elt => {
  elt.onclick = () => {
    resume(event.target, false);
  }
});

document.querySelectorAll('.resumeBtn').forEach(elt => {
  elt.onclick = () => {
    resume(event.target, true);
  }
});
```

```css
.crossOut {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone number</th>
      <th scope="col">Application time</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td scope="row" class="appOrd">Name</td>
      <td class="appOrd">Phone number</td>
      <td class="appOrd">2021-02-07 08:40:48</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-success resumeBtn disabled" href="#">Resume</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger completeBtn" href="#">Complete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td scope="row" class="appOrd">Name1</td>
      <td class="appOrd">Phone number1</td>
      <td class="appOrd">2021-02-08 08:40:48</td>
      <td>
        <a class="btn btn-success resumeBtn disabled" href="#">Resume</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger completeBtn" href="#">Complete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, it still only crosses out `Name`, not the rest of the cells.

Comment: sorry, please try again

Comment: I have updated my answer to illustrate my point, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is best approach OR not.

You can query the table rows (`tbody tr`) and add handlers by querying the `Complete and Resume` buttons and toggle the classes based clicks. In this way, you can handle the rows(`tr`) smoothly.

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')

rows.forEach(row => {
   const completeBtn = row.querySelector('.completeBtn');
   const resumeBtn = row.querySelector('.resumeBtn');
   const appOrds = row.querySelectorAll('.appOrd');
   
   completeBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     appOrds.forEach(el => el.classList.add('crossOut'));
     resumeBtn.classList.remove('disabled');
     this.classList.add('disabled');
   })

   resumeBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     appOrds.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('crossOut'));
     completeBtn.classList.remove('disabled');
     this.classList.add('disabled');
   })
})
```

```css
.crossOut{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Phone number</th>
          <th scope="col">Application time</th>
          <th scope="col">Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <td scope="row" class="appOrd">Name</td>
          <td class="appOrd">Phone number</td>
          <td class="appOrd">2021-02-07 08:40:48</td>
          <td>
            <a class="btn btn-success resumeBtn disabled" href="#">Resume</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger completeBtn" href="#">Complete</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
<tr class="text-center">
          <td scope="row" class="appOrd">Name</td>
          <td class="appOrd">Phone number</td>
          <td class="appOrd">2021-02-07 08:40:48</td>
          <td>
            <a class="btn btn-success resumeBtn disabled" href="#">Resume</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger completeBtn" href="#">Complete</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: You still need an explanation after all seeing these answers. ;-(

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works, but only for the first row of the table, for some reason it doesn't work for the second.

Comment: YW @Hi_TecH, it just same as Barmar answer but different way of doing it(adding event listeners).

Comment: Oh I got it, issue is, we are registering `click` handler for only one button using (`querySelector`), we need to register for all `buttons`. Let me try to fix it.